# bash: antlr4: command not found... I am getting this error while giving antlr4 Hello.g4 in terminal , pls anyone can help me with this?

Tags: intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4

[**bash: antlr4: command not found... I am getting this error while giving antlr4 Hello.g4 in terminal , pls anyone can help me with this?**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuY2F.png)

Comment: [srinivasan@Ipd-Srini FirstProject]$ antlr4 Hello.g4
bash: antlr4: command not found...
Similar command is: 'antlr'

Answer (score 1):

`antlr4` itself is not a command. It is an alias you have to define yourself. See the [getting started](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) guide on the ANTLR GitHub page for how to do that.